# Apply function to pandas dataframe row using values in other rows

Tags: python, pandas, lambda, dataframe

I have a situation where I have a dataframe row to perform calculations with, and I need to use values in following (potentially preceding) rows to do these calculations (essentially a perfect forecast based on the real data set). I get each row from an earlier `df.apply` call, so I could pass the whole df along to the downstream objects, but that seems less than ideal based on the complexity of objects in my analysis.

I found one closely related question and answer [1], but the problem is actually fundamentally different in the sense that I do not need the whole df for my calcs, simply the following `x` number of rows (which might matter for large dfs).

So, for example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700, 800, 900, 1000], 
                  columns=['PRICE'])
horizon = 3
```

I need to access values in the following 3 (`horizon`) rows in my row-wise `df.apply` call. How can I get a naive forecast of the next 3 data points dynamically in my row-wise apply calcs? e.g. for row the first row, where the `PRICE` is `100`, I need to use `[200, 300, 400]` as a forecast in my calcs.

[1] [apply a function to a pandas Dataframe whose returned value is based on other rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14429793/apply-a-function-to-a-pandas-dataframe-whose-retuned-value-is-based-on-other-row)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

By getting the row's index inside of the `df.apply()` call using [`row.name`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26658240/getting-the-index-of-a-row-in-a-pandas-apply-function), you can generate the 'forecast' data relative to which row you are currently on. This is effectively a preprocessing step to put the 'forecast' onto the relevant row, or it could be done as part of the initial `df.apply()` call if the df is available downstream.

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(
    [100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700, 800, 900, 1000],
    columns=["PRICE"]
)
horizon = 3
    
df["FORECAST"] = df.apply(
    lambda x: [df["PRICE"][x.name + 1 : x.name + horizon + 1]],
    axis=1
)
```

Results in this:

```
   PRICE          FORECAST
0    100   [200, 300, 400]
1    200   [300, 400, 500]
2    300   [400, 500, 600]
3    400   [500, 600, 700]
4    500   [600, 700, 800]
5    600   [700, 800, 900]
6    700  [800, 900, 1000]
7    800       [900, 1000]
8    900            [1000]
9   1000                []
```

Which can be used in your row-wise `df.apply()` calcs.

**EDIT:**
If you want to strip the index from the resulting 'Forecast':

```py
df["FORECAST"] = df.apply(
    lambda x: [df["PRICE"][x.name + 1 : x.name + horizon + 1].reset_index(drop=True)],
    axis=1
)
```

Answer (score 2):

You may find this useful as well.

```
keys = range(horizon + 1)
pd.concat([df.shift(-i) for i in keys], axis=1, keys=keys)

      0       1       2       3
  PRICE   PRICE   PRICE   PRICE
0   100   200.0   300.0   400.0
1   200   300.0   400.0   500.0
2   300   400.0   500.0   600.0
3   400   500.0   600.0   700.0
4   500   600.0   700.0   800.0
5   600   700.0   800.0   900.0
6   700   800.0   900.0  1000.0
7   800   900.0  1000.0     NaN
8   900  1000.0     NaN     NaN
9  1000     NaN     NaN     NaN
```

if you assign the `concat` to `df_c`

```
keys = range(horizon + 1)
df_c = pd.concat([df.shift(-i) for i in keys], axis=1, keys=keys)

df_c.apply(lambda x: pd.Series([x[0].values, x[1:].values]), axis=1)

          0                       1
0   [100.0]   [200.0, 300.0, 400.0]
1   [200.0]   [300.0, 400.0, 500.0]
2   [300.0]   [400.0, 500.0, 600.0]
3   [400.0]   [500.0, 600.0, 700.0]
4   [500.0]   [600.0, 700.0, 800.0]
5   [600.0]   [700.0, 800.0, 900.0]
6   [700.0]  [800.0, 900.0, 1000.0]
7   [800.0]    [900.0, 1000.0, nan]
8   [900.0]      [1000.0, nan, nan]
9  [1000.0]         [nan, nan, nan]
```

Comment: Do you think there is a performance benefit one way or the other, and under what circumstances?

Comment: @lukewitmer No, I just ran `%%timeit` and your wat is 5+ times quicker.  I like my way because I find it more elegent.  But I'd go with you way because its plenty intuitive and its quicker.