# pandas Dataframe, assign value based on selection of other rows

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas DataFrame in python 3.

In this DataFrame there are rows which have identical values in two columns (this can be whole sections), I'll call this a group.
Each row also has a `True`/`False` value in a column.

Now for each row I want to know if *any* of the rows in its group have a `False` value, if so, I want to assign a `False` value to every row in that group in another column. I've managed to do this in a for-loop, but it's quite slow:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'E': [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],
                   'D': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
                   'C': [True, True, False, False, True, True, True],
                   'B': ['aa', 'aa', 'aa', 'bb', 'cc', 'dd', 'dd'],
                   'A': [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1]})
```

Which gives:

```
df:
     A   B      C  D    E
  0  0  aa   True  0  NaN
  1  0  aa   True  1  NaN
  2  0  aa  False  2  NaN
  3  0  bb  False  3  NaN
  4  1  cc   True  4  NaN
  5  1  dd   True  5  NaN
  6  1  dd   True  6  NaN
```

Now I run the for-loop:

```
for i in df.index:
    df.ix[i, 'E'] = df[(df['A'] == df.iloc[i]['A']) & (df['B'] == df.iloc[i]['B'])]['C'].all()
```

which then gives the desired result:

```
df:
     A   B      C  D      E
  0  0  aa   True  0  False
  1  0  aa   True  1  False
  2  0  aa  False  2  False
  3  0  bb  False  3  False
  4  1  cc   True  4   True
  5  1  dd   True  5   True
  6  1  dd   True  6   True
```

When running this for my entire DataFrame of ~1 million rows this takes ages. So, looking at using `.apply()` to avoid a for-loop I've stumbled across the following question: [apply a function to a pandas Dataframe whose retuned value is based on other rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14429793/apply-a-function-to-a-pandas-dataframe-whose-retuned-value-is-based-on-other-row)

however:

```
def f(x): return False not in x
df.groupby(['A','B']).C.apply(f)
```

returns:

```
A  B 
0  aa    False
   bb     True
1  cc     True
   dd     True
```

Does anyone know a better way or how to fix the last case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try doing a SQL-style join using `pd.merge`.

Perform the same groupby that you're doing, but apply min() to it to look for any cases with C == True. Then convert that to a DataFrame, rename the column as "E", and merge it back to df.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'D': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
               'C': [True, True, False, False, True, True, True],
               'B': ['aa', 'aa', 'aa', 'bb', 'cc', 'dd', 'dd'],
               'A': [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1]})

falses = pd.DataFrame(df.groupby(['A', 'B']).C.min() == True)
falses = falses.rename(columns={'C': 'E'})

df = df.merge(falses, left_on=['A', 'B'], right_index=True)
```

Comment: Works great and fast! However, `...C.min() == False` should check for `True` instead